# 'Discretize' a continuous variable - but not 'factorize' it

Tags: r, simulation

I am trying to run a monte carlo simulation and part of what I want to do is repeat a process as a key variable becomes more and more 'discrete' (ignore that the idea of 'more discrete' is basically meaningless).

So if x <- rnorm(100), and has a range of (-4,3) I want to be able to slowly make it more discrete by first 'rounding' the 100 observations into 1,000 intervals (so the values equal the middle of the interval say), then 500, then 100 etc until it is 'binary' with only 2 intervals.

For example, here is what it would look like with an ugly (and inefficient) double loop:

```
    n = 1000
    x <- rnorm(n)
    k = 20
    points <- seq(from = min(x), to = max(x), length.out = k)
    for(i in 1:n){   
          for(j in 1:k){          
                if(x[i] < points[j]){
                      x[i] <- mean(c(points[j], points[j-1])) 
                      break
                }
          }      
    }
```

I have tried 'cut', and multiple different variations of the 'apply'/'sapply' but nothing gives me what I want. And the above loop works fine, but takes forever. And if I want to simulate convergence etc. this may run for weeks depending on the set up.

Any help on what I may be

Answer (score 1):

`cut()` should probably work for these type of work, but here is an approach using `sapply` - loops:

```
#dummy data
set.seed(1234)
n = 1000
x <- rnorm(n)

#Discretize a continuous variable
z <- 
  sapply(c(100,10,5,3), function(k){
    sapply(1:length(x), function(i){
      points <- seq(from = min(x), to = max(x), length.out = k)
      mean(c(points[which(x[i]>points)][1],
           points[which(x[i]<points)][1]))
    })
  })

#plot hist
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
hist(z[,1])
hist(z[,2])
hist(z[,3])
hist(z[,4])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of job, use the very efficient `findInterval`.

I'd try:

```
((points[-k]+points[-1])/2)[findInterval(x,points)]
```

First you evaluate the mean of each value of `point` with its next. Then you assign the corresponding mean value to the interval occupied by the `x` value.

Comment: This doesn't give the same values for the min/max values as OP's solution.